# classes autoload doesn't work when imported from another file

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

My autoload.php doesn't load a required class when i import it from another file:

This is the class i autoload from:

main.php:

```
use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;
require '/library/vendor/autoload.php';

class Main {
    __construct() {
    $this->socketIOClient = new Client(new Version2X('someWebsite'));
    }
}
```

The following script works:

```
require 'main.php';
$main = new Main();
```

However this script doesnt:

```
require '/library/vendor/autoload.php';
require 'main.php';

class NotWorking extends Thread {
    __construct() {
        $this->main = new Main();
    }
}
$nowWorking = new NotWorking();

Output:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ElephantIO\Client' not found in main.php
```

Why is that so and whats the way to properly autoload again?

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT:

The problem was that i used pthreads and classes which extend thread dont behave normally when requiring autoload.php.

Comment: I dont see how the first script is working. You are trying to use a class before including the autoload. It should be the first script throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the require first.

```
require '/library/vendor/autoload.php';

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;
```

Comment: The problem was that i used pthreads and classes which extend thread dont behave normally when requiring autoload.php.